# Finding minimum cut edges in a graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, complexity-theory

Given a random undirected graph, I must find 'bottleneck edges' (edit: minimum cut edges) to get from one vertex to another.

What I call 'bottleneck edges' (edit: minimum cut edges) -- 
suppose I have the following undirected graph:

```
    A
  / | \
 B--C--D
 |     |
 E--F--G
  \ | /
    H
```

To get from A to H independently of the chosen path edges BE and DG must always be traversed, therefore making a 'bottleneck' (edit: minimum cut).

Is there a polynomial time algorithm for this?

Comment: Would HE HF and HG also be considered bottlenecks? Do you have a different definition?

Comment: This sounds very much like the [Travelling salesman problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) except replace distances with computational time. Specifically related to your question is the [Bottleneck traveling salesman problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bottleneck_traveling_salesman_problem)

Comment: You mean edge BE **or** DG must always be traversed?

Comment: sawa: Yes, saying BE or DG could be more correct

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sounds like you need minimum cut, the minimal set of edges removing which will separate your graph into two pieces.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_cut

Comment: This might well be it. And use Max flow = min-cut :-)

Comment: Thanks, yes, minimum cut it is! :)

Answer (score 5):

What you are looking for is a [**cut**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut_%28graph_theory%29). Given a graph, a cut is a set of edges that partitions the vertices into two disjoint subsets.

Assuming you are trying to get the smallest cut possible, this is the classic **min-cut** problem. Here is a pseudo code version of the [Ford-fulkerson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ford_Fulkerson) algorithm, reworked for your case (undirected, unweighted graphs). I'm pretty sure it should work, but I am not sure I'm being the most efficient / idiomatic here.

```
reorganize your graph into a directed graph,
  with two directed edges (u->v, v->u) for each original edge (u-v)

while there is a path P from A to H:
  (hint: use breadth first search to find paths - long story here)
  //augment the path P:
  for each edge (u->v) in P:
    remove (u->v) from the graph and add (v->u) to it
    (if v->u isn't there already)

Label all vertices as reacheable or not reacheable from A.

The bottleneck edges is the set of edges
  that connect a reacheable and a unreacheable vertex
```

---

For example, in your case BFS would give us the path A-B-E-H. After removing these edges, we would still be able to find the path A-D-G-H. After these edges are removed, the graph is partitioned into the reacheable vertices {A,B,C,D} and the unreacheable {E,F,G,H}. The edges that have a vertex from each (B-E and D-G) set are the bottleneck edges.

Comment: I forgot if using BFS would allow us to straight up remove the edges (in this unweighted, undirected), instead of doing all the directed edge stuff. Does anyone remember this?